# How to decode this html string using C#?

Tags: c#, html

I have some string with javascript format string following :

```
\u003Cdiv>\u003Cdiv class=\"mbm detail_research\">\u003Cdiv class=\"clearfix\">\u003Ca class=\"_8o _8r lfloat\" href=\"http:\/\/www.abcm.com\/mutily\/post.php?id=2344324342\"
```

Anyone know about how to decode it to normal html string using C#?

My mean that it will become to :

```
<div><div class="mbm detail_research"><div class="clearfix"><a class="_8o _8r lfloat" href="http://www.abcm.com/mutily/post.php?id=2344324342"
```

after decoded.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: We decode does you mean, how to parse it?

Comment: Yeah @Deepesh. This is my mean. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: My answer is updated..will you try it??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is `Regex.Unescape`

```
var decodedString = Regex.Unescape(yourString);
```

Answer (score 4):

use HttpUtility Class to decode it as :

```
String myDecodedString = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("Html encoded String here");
```

Follow this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7c5fyk1k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) article

Comment: I know about HttpUtility but my question is how to decode it. It's not html encode. Thanks!

Comment: so, update your answer that what type of decode you want??plz mention it in Question...